# onclick= copyToClipboard: for php variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, variables, copy

So I use the following code in php to copy any div, but how can I edit the js code to copy a php variable in the page, like `$bookid` or `$row[1]` (or copy/echo two strings like `$bookid . $row[1]` with one click) etc.?

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#div1')\">Copy</button>
```

js code:

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

Comment: php code only executed from serverside and js execute from client side. First you have to store php value to js variable like ```var $phpValue = <?php echo $bookid . $row[1]; ?>```, then you can copy the ```$phpValue``` data to clipboard.

Comment: Thanks @AnisurRahman for the reply.  I replaced the `  var $temp = $("<input>");` in the js with `var $phpValue = <?php echo $bookid . $row[7]; ?>;`, but the output gives the error `"Undefined variable: phpValue"`. How to define it in the php? - Also, if I set `$bookid` in the js, do I need to do that for each variable I have?

Comment: You're replacing the wrong thing to begin with. Not this needs replacing (that is the input field the browser will actually copy the value _from_), but the `$temp.val($(element).text())` part does. Instead of reading the text content of `element`, you want to directly supply a string value there.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe , I am a bit new to this. Can you add an answer with the needed edits for the above js/php code to reflect that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text that gets copied here, is the content of the dynamically created input field. Currently that gets set by reading the text content of `element` - so that is the part that needs replacing.

```js
function copyToClipboard(textToCopy) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(textToCopy).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('hello world')">Copy</button>
```